# How to return GPO applied firewall rules (INetFwPolicy2.Rules)?

Tags: c#, powershell, windows-firewall, windows-firewall-api

Here is the C# code to return Firewall rules:

```
Type tNetFwPolicy2 = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2");

INetFwPolicy2 fwPolicy2 = (INetFwPolicy2)Activator.CreateInstance(tNetFwPolicy2);

List<INetFwRule> RuleList = new List<INetFwRule>();

foreach (INetFwRule rule in fwPolicy2.Rules)
{
    RuleList.Add(rule);
}
```

With Powershell this returns the same:

```
Get-NetFirewallRule
```

However Powershell also has the -PolicyStore param. If we use:

```
Get-NetFirewallRule -PolicyStore RSOP
```

or

```
Get-NetFirewallRule -PolicyStore ActiveStore
```

It will return all the rules enforced by the domain group policy.

Is there something similar that can be done with C#?

Comment: `Get-NetFirewallRule` uses the `MSFT_NetFirewallRule` CIM class, so you should be able to use that.

Comment: Just tried this with the scope "\\\\.\\ROOT\\StandardCimv2" and query "SELECT * FROM MSFT_NetFirewallRule" but it only gave me the local rules. Is there a path where the group policy rules are stored locally?

Comment: Strange there is a PolicyStoreSource property. But how can MSFT_NetFirewallRule be populated with different policy stores?

Comment: I haven't used that CIM class; my comment was intended to get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: You can't. The API does not expose them.

Comment: Hi flux. Did you solve this problem? I also have this problem. If you solved, please help me

Comment: I think I went a different route using netsh to do what I needed to do (long time ago)